# OpenGL Chess Pieces

Tags: opengl, graphics, glut

I need to make a chess set in OpenGL and want to know if this is the right way to go.

This is the code for the pawn piece:

```
void pawn(void)
{

    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    DrawArc(xc+6, yc-3,1.3,M_PI/2,M_PI/2,25);
    DrawArc(xc+6.7, yc-3,1.3,M_PI/2,-M_PI/2,25);
    DrawArc(xc+6, yc-0.9,0.8,M_PI/2,M_PI,25);
    DrawArc(xc+6.7, yc-0.9,0.8,M_PI/2,-M_PI,25);
    DrawArc(xc+6.35, yc+0.25,0.5,(7*M_PI)/4,(3*M_PI)/2,25);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2d(xc+4.7,yc-3);
        glVertex2d(xc+8,yc-3);
    glEnd();

    glFlush ();
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Using a model? Making a chess piece in a 3D modelling program shouldn't prove too difficult, and then allows you to make use of more efficient features in OpenGL like Vertex Buffer Objects and get to grips with loading models in.

Comment: You can still use vertex buffers or VBOs from code... just means you have to fill in some buffers in memory.

Comment: Unless there's some specific problem that your code is producing, "better" is a pretty vague term to work with.

Answer (score 5):

Creating geometry in code isn't the most efficient method.

The common way is to:

- create the model in a 3D modelling tool such as Blender (free)
- save it to a file, such as `.ply` or `.obj`
- load the geometry to the graphics card memory (a [Vertex Buffer Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object))
- render it using `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`

Comment: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/ has some nice tutorials of modern OpenGL, including loading models with the `Assimp` library

Comment: I know this, but the point is to create it in code. This is homework.

Comment: Well, you asked whether it's a good way :-) Let me know how I can provide more help

Comment: Well, i want to draw the whole pawn and fill the inside with white color (so i get a white pawn). How do i do that? :)

Comment: Either draw the pawn using white triangles or draw one rectangle textured with a pawn image.